# Do Squid Beacons count towards the Super Jump Spot medal?

Tags: splatoon-3

One of the post-game medals you can get is #1 Super Jump Spot. Looking at the name I assume it is awarded based on how many times a teammate Super Jumps to your location.

Do Super Jumps to a Squid Beacon I've placed count toward the Super Jump Spot medal?

[image: #1 Super Jump Spot award]